# How use ' '.join() in Python?

Tags: cpython

I was studying PEP8's [Programming Recommendations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id51).

It was recommended to use `''.join` to combine strings, but I did not understand when to do so:

1. Should I concatenate every time that way?
2. How useful is this?
3. At what times are ideal to use `join()` to String? In Path, URL, Texts?

In [PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/
Should this have been `return ' '.join('Hello', name)` ?

Comment: Use `str.join` for large strings. In particular, if constructing a large string, first create a list, then use `str.join` on it instead of using `+=` on an (at first) empty string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine you have four strings: `a`, `b`, `c` and `d`.

Say you want their concatenation, `e = a + b + c + d`. However, the `+` operator is only defined for two operands, so you would apparently need to concatenate the individual strings one by one.

The naive way to calculate this might be the following:

```
e = ((a + b) + c) + d
```

But this is inefficient, because it generates two throwaway strings: `a + b` and `a + b + c`.

Now, imagine we created a buffer-like object holding all the characters we wanted to combine:

```
e_buffer = [a, b, c, d]
```

We could create `e` from this *all at once*, avoiding the need to create many intermediate strings.

This requires a function, which, in Python, we call `join`; it is a method of a `str`, and intersperses that string between the arguments provided. Therefore, when you execute `some_separator.join([a, b, c])`, you get, in effect, `a + some_separator + b + some_separator + c`.

To answer your question: in general, when concatenating many strings, it should be faster to use `join`, and it will at least be more readable, especially when using a separator. For the case given in the question, I would instead use an f-string:

```
def greeting(name: str) -> str:
    return f'Hello {name}'
```

Comment: For a case like this, `+` is fine. The real problems start happening when you concatenate strings with `+` or `+=` in a *loop*, where you're likely to have far more than 4 strings to concatenate.